Date conversion in specific format is giving me NA values
I have created a sample data frame and while converting the column into specific date format for some cases it is showing NA. Below is the code I have used to create a data frame and the format which I have used for conversion.
test_df <- data.frame(
  Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), 
  Date_1 = c("13-02-2014", "15-03-2013", "4/8/2011", "4/9/2014", "16-02-2017", "26-02-2017", "16-02-2018", "3/3/2014")
 
)

test_df$Final_Date <- as.Date(test_df$Date_1, "%d-%m-%Y")



However, after conversion for Id 3, 4, 8 it is giving NA values and for remaining it is working correctly.
Is there any way I can resolve the issue?

The issue is that some dates have - and some have /. The values in Date_1 for Id 3, 4, and 8 have a /, so %d-%m-Y doesn't work for those ones. You can use lubridate::dmy. It doesn't care if the dates have - or /. It just looks for dates with the day first, followed by the month, and then the year.
library(lubridate)
test_df <- data.frame(
  Id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), 
  Date_1 = c("13-02-2014", "15-03-2013", "4/8/2011", "4/9/2014", "16-02-2017", "26-02-2017", "16-02-2018", "3/3/2014"))
test_df$Final_Date <- dmy(test_df$Date_1)
print(test_df)

Id     Date_1 Final_Date
1  1 13-02-2014 2014-02-13
2  2 15-03-2013 2013-03-15
3  3   4/8/2011 2011-08-04
4  4   4/9/2014 2014-09-04
5  5 16-02-2017 2017-02-16
6  6 26-02-2017 2017-02-26
7  7 16-02-2018 2018-02-16
8  8   3/3/2014 2014-03-03


Thanks Dave the above solution worked for me

I do not see where you are using the tagged {lubridate} (deleted therefore), moreover it is not needed.
as.Date(gsub("/", "-", test_df$Date_1), "%d-%m-%Y")

